# Recommendation how to find missing translations in vue-18n?

Tags: vue-i18n

Is there a recommendation how to create a unit test for missing strings used in templates that are missing in a specific locale file? I'm using vue-18n.

Answer (score 1):

You have in vuei18n the missing function - default behavior : it writes to log warning of what string is missing, and uses the key instead.

If you want you can override this behavior - check [documentation](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/migrations.html#missinghandler-replaced).

The problem with it is that if a component isn't rendered yet, you won't see the warning till you try to render it..